# Getting list back from ajax jsonp callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an ajax call via jquery with a jsonp callback function. The callback gets called and generates a list for me that I need to return to the original alling function and assign to a variable. However, it is not getting passed back. I know I am doing something wrong or misunderstanding how this flow works. Could somebody please point me in the correct direction? Here is the (abbreviated) code:

```
function() {
  ..build url...
  var multiTargets = getMultiMetrics(url);
  ...do stuff with list...
}



getMultiMetrics = function(url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp : true,
    jsonpCallback: 'metricCallback',
    cache: true,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    async: false
});
};

metricCallback = function(data) {
  var items = [];
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    items.push(data[i].target);
  };
  return items;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried adding: completed?

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance but, I am not entirely sure how I would use that in this context. .complete is on the initial ajax call. How do I get the data from the jsonp callback?

Comment: Its no problem: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   See 'Complete'under settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try not use quotes in 
`jsonpCallback: metricCallback,`
This parameter must be function instead of a string